# SQL update with insert subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql I want to do something like this

```
update users set salary_account_id = 
(insert into salary_accounts(some_field) values(1) returning salary_account_id)
```

I want for every record in user table to create corresponding salary_account record and then update users table with corresponding newly created salary_account_id

If I run this query I get an error 'syntax error at or near "into"'.

Comment: You should probably make that `insert` into a function, which would do the insert and return the new ID. This can't be done as written.

Comment: What is the relation between `users` and `salary_account`? I can't imagine you want to change **all** users to the salary_account_id you have just inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two separate queries. something like this:

```
insert into salary_accounts(some_field, user_fk, ...)
select 1, user_uid, .. from users;

update update users u 
set salary_account_id = (select salary_account_id from salary_accounts where user_fk = user_uid);
```

Or If you do not have the user_fk in salary_accounts table then you will need something like this:

```
update update users u 
set salary_account_id = some_sequence;

insert into salary_accounts(some_field, salary_account_id , ...)
select 1, salary_account_id , .. from users;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two combine the two statements into one, you need to use a CTE:

```
with inserted as (
  insert into salary_accounts(some_field) 
  values (1) 
  returning salary_account_id
)
update users 
  set salary_account_id = (select salary_account_id from inserted)
where ???
```

You will **have** to add a WHERE clause to restrict the users you want to update as I can't imagine you want to update **all** users to the same `salary_account_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CreateSalaryAccount()
RETURNS integer AS $func$
declare
    a_id integer;
BEGIN
  insert into salary_accounts(some_val) values(1) returning salary_account_id into a_id;
  RETURN a_id;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdateUsersTable() 
  RETURNS VOID 
AS
$$
DECLARE 
   t_row users%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR t_row in SELECT * FROM users LOOP
        update users
            set salary_account_id = CreateSalaryAccount()
        where id = t_row.id;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select UpdateUsersTable()
```